# transfer contents from Jtextarea to file not working when screen is locked

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have a Jtextarea in my program in which I write unicode text using Java Robot. Now, once I have written 1000 lines, I create a text file and transfer the contents of Jtextarea to the file. But the problem is that I only manage to get 200 or 300 lines written to the file. I think, this happens because I lock the screen after a few seconds of running the program to let the program run on its own and my doing so doesn't allow robot to write to the Jtextarea anymore. I tested this by once staying for entire first 1000 lines and as a result got all the 1000 lines transferred to the file. The problem can also be with the Google input tools which converts whatever the robot writes in English to Hindi in the Jtextarea (Maybe it doesn't work when the screen locks).

Is there any way by which I can lock the screen and Robot continues to function? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Following is the relevant parts of the code:-

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

static JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(); 
static Robot robot = null;

public MainClass()
{
    getContentPane().add(ta,BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    try {
        robot= new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO  Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br = null;

    MainClass mclass= new MainClass();
    mclass.setLocation(100,100); 
    mclass.setTitle("Robot Demo");
    mclass.setSize(200,200);
    mclass.show();

    //br reads from the input file
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Avinash\\Downloads\\NamedEntitiesInHeadlines.txt"));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    //The 4 keystrokes below convert the OS input language form English to Hindi and enables the Google input tools
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);                    

    robot.delay(3000);

    int countLines=1;
    int countFiles=1;
    String sCurrentLine=null;
    try {
        while((sCurrentLine= br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(countLines);
            sCurrentLine= sCurrentLine.trim();

            /////////////The preprocessing below ultimately gives the string needed i.e. toBeWritten
            if(sCurrentLine.length()>0)
            {
                String[] entities = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

                String toBeWritten="";

                for(int i=0;i<entities.length;i++)
                {
                    String s= entities[i];
                    s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);

                    String[] wordAndEntity= s.split(":::");

                    toBeWritten += wordAndEntity[0];
                    toBeWritten += " ::: ";
                }

                mclass.type(toBeWritten);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            }
            else
            { //if there is an empty line then type an empty line
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            }

            //write to a new file every 1000 line 
            if(countLines%1000==0)
            {   
                File fileDir = new File("C:\\Users\\Avinash\\Downloads\\NamedEntitiesConvertedToHindi"+countFiles+".txt");
                Writer outfile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir,true), "UTF8"));
                ta.transferFocus();
                robot.delay(1000);
                try
                {
                ta.write(outfile);
                }
                finally
                {
                outfile.flush();
                outfile.close();
                }
                ta.requestFocus();
                robot.delay(5000);
                ta.setText("");
                robot.delay(500);
                countFiles++;
            }
            countLines++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    robot.delay(5000);

    //toggle back the OS input language to English
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    ta.transferFocus();
    robot.delay(1000);

    //write any lines that are left
    File fileDir = new File("C:\\Users\\Avinash\\Downloads\\NamedEntitiesConvertedToHindi.txt");
    Writer outfile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir,true), "UTF8"));
    ta.write(outfile);
    outfile.flush();
    outfile.close();
    System.out.println("FINISHED THE WORK");


    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give any sample code?

Comment: @NonExistent....Sure....updated the question

Answer (score 0):

The [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class is used to generate native system input events. If your OS/workstation is locked, then the generated native events will not be executed by the OS.

You can't lock your OS and continue to use `Robot` to input text into your `JTextArea`.

I don't know your code (because you haven't posted any), but if the `Robot` is in the same Java program than your `JTextArea`, then you should absolutely not use `Robot` to write text into the text area, instead use the `JTextArea`'s methods to do that (e.g. `JTextArea.setText()`, `JTextArea.getDocument()`).

If they are in 2 separate Java applications, you can transfer the text in other ways like Sockets, files etc.

Comment: @icza....true....but I can't use JtextArea.setText() because then Google input tools will not intercept what is being input and thus I won't get a Hindi language input. For that I have to emulate keystrokes.... Also, I have updated the question with the code